# App is not running in lower sdk than 21 though the minSdk is 17

Tags: android, android-cardview, androiddesignsupport, android-min-sdk

In my app previously I added cardview and material tab. The app was running in all compatible device from SDK 17-21, but after adding the support design library, the app is crashing on SDKs lower than 21.

My dependencies are:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch:library:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
compile 'com.github.mrengineer13:snackbar:1.2.0'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.4@aar'
compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
compile 'io.karim:materialtabs:2.0.2'
compile 'com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext:library:0.0.6'
compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.10@aar'
compile 'com.github.lawloretienne:imagegallery:0.0.8'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.bowyer.app:fabtransitionlayout:0.2.0@aar'
compile 'me.tatarka.support:jobscheduler:0.1.1'
```

Part of cardView

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view1"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        >
```

LogCat shows:

```
    11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.razon30.totalmovie, PID: 32692
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.CardViewEclairMr1.getShadowBackground(CardViewEclairMr1.java:159)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.CardViewEclairMr1.getMinWidth(CardViewEclairMr1.java:150)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.onMeasure(CardView.java:181)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5374)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.measureChildWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:6934)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1397)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1334)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:563)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2847)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3145)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1627)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15125)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2347)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2053)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6255)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
11-05 14:44:23.276 32692-32692/com.example.razon30.totalmovie E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.vie
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You cant cast a ColorDrawable to a RoundRectDrawableWithShadow

Comment: Will you please explain more :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this it wotks

```
 cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: But brother, i didn't add any background color to cardView
I have updated my question by adding the cardView part

Comment: I just got the same error when called using **cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);** after changing it by this **cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); cardView.setRadius(50);** it's started to work

Answer (score 0):

card views represented in the api level 21 and after that, so it is not surprising that it does not run in the devices with api level lower than 21.

Comment: I don't think so, cause i am using the same cardView since the project's starting. Earlier it worked very well. 
I don't know why i am facing such problem that none has the actual solution :(